# PhysicsCollision Cocos2d/Swift

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I am writing 2d game using Cocos2d-iphone in new Apple programming language Swift. I am having problem with collision detection. I have added `CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate` and implemented `CCPhysicsCollisionBegin` method in my class but when I try to run it I get following error:

```
'CCPhysicsCollisionBegin delegate methods must return a BOOL.'
```

Here is what my method looks like:

```
func ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(pair: CCPhysicsCollisionPair!, aMan nodeA: CCNode!, fuel nodeB: CCNode!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: you method name/signature doesn't match

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT: Looks like this may have been a bug in Swift. I cannot recreate this anymore with the current version of Xcode. Seems like you can just return Bool now.**

You'll need to return the ObjCBool type since Cocos2D-swift is written in Objective-C.

Your method should look like:

```
func ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(pair: CCPhysicsCollisionPair!, aMan nodeA: CCNode!, fuel nodeB: CCNode!) -> ObjCBool {
        return true
}
```

You can also use:

```
func ccPhysicsCollisionBegin(pair: CCPhysicsCollisionPair!, aMan: CCNode!, fuel: CCNode!) -> ObjCBool {
        return true
}
```

And then reference the collided nodes with aMan and fuel instead of nodeA and nodeB.

Comment: It's not ObjcCBool but ObjCBool, please edit your answer for others who may see this question. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem with my project. I had to change my ccPhysicsCollisionBegin methods to return ObjCBool in order to run on an physical device. I can get away with using Bool when it's running in the simulator, but a physical device needs ObjCBool to run without throwing an exception.

Using Xcode 6.2